# How to implement custom field to show a modal to add a new CRUD?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I need to make "add new" button on select2_multiple field. Which show a modal to add new item.

I have no idea how to implement this type of custom field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check out https://github.com/webfactor/laravel-backpack-instant-fields - they've already created a field type with this functionality, but I believe it's only for 1-n relations.

Creating a new field type isn't difficult at all, it's just adding one blade file in your `resources/views/backpack/crud/fields` folder. [Documentation here](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type). That file will include all the PHP and JS logic you want. However, creating this particular field type will be more complicated, it will involve a lot of Javascript, and most likely an AJAX request to a route and controller method you create.

In Backpack v4 we plan for this to be an official feature. We're still 1-2 months away from v4, though.

Comment: Not working with the laravel installation version v7.19.1

Comment: I'm also trying to add a button to open a model where I can set relations for two diff entities.